# How to scroll jQuery dialog if the page is too short?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I found a very nice example using Twitter's bootstrap: http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

It is the first demo. So if you make the page really short, you can scroll to see the bottom of the modal while the rest of the page doesn't scroll at all. Is there an easy way to do this without using bootstrap and just using jQuery?

Comment: If you're remotely curious how they do it the scrolling modal box is actually a normal div with the usual close buttons, content and normal close button at the bottom. The container for this however, is styled with `position: fixed; overflow-y: scroll;` to make the internal element scroll where required.

Comment: I think that if you have enough content to require scrolling, you probably shouldn't be using a modal in the first place.

Comment: @Blazemonger For like 99% of our user, it really isn't a problem. But for some people with really small screens and we don't have responsive designs built in yet, this is a problem. Would rather not change everything for the majority of our users for just a handful.